# Kotlin Android порядок выполнения кода

Tags: android, функции, kotlin, порядок

[image: На картинке выделено присвоение главное и возвращение]

У меня есть функция, которая возвращает значение info, но происходит так, что возвращается info="", сначала идет блок вне when, а потом всередине, как это исправить?

Comment: Полагаю функция асинхронная  и код выполняется раньше, чем, что-то придёт из ответа и обработается

Comment: Как исправить? Изучать основы асинхронного программирования в общем и Kotlin suspended functions в частности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу самый простой способ это переделать функцию `readRoom()` в асинхронную

```
fun readRoom(_room: String, onSuccess: (String) -> Unit) {
    val infoAboutRoom = ...
    infoAboutRoom. ... .addOnSuccessListener {
        val info = when(...) {
            ...
        }
        onSuccess(info)
    }
    Log.d(...)
}
```